# Deploy application in kubernetes as pod vs deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I have the following scenario:

Application starts and runs puppeteer monitoring youtube channel, each application monitors a different channel, same code, just a different channel ID as environment variable.

There is no scaling for this application, one instance monitors one channel

My question is:

- what would be the best deployment option in k8s?

  - Deployment of single Pod
  - Just a Pod
  - Job (technically each service is not a job there is no task timeout)

best deployment means the easiest way to manage and rollout new app version to all running pods.

Answer (score 1):

The best option for your use case is to use Kubernetes Deployment as it has a lot of features that can be helpful. Since you mentioned that you’ll be rolling out new app versions to all running pods, Kubernetes Deployment updates image & environment variables while maintaining uptime and availability of your services. Minimal downtime as the deployment ensures that if a pod dies it will create a new one from its replicas. Rollback is also an option in case you need to go back to previous versions. Attached is a documentation for more details.[1]

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/